# Can't use Shadow DOM in Chrome 37?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, shadow-dom

Not sure why I can't seem to use the shadow DOM. I'm in Chrome 37 and I've tried using a couple shadow DOM tutorials or demo's and none of them work?

```
<div>Hello, World!</div>
<script>
  var host = document.querySelector('div');
  var root = host.webkitCreateShadowRoot();
  root.textContent = 'Hello, Underworld!';
</script>
```

Do you see anything wrong with this? I've tried it just viewing it in the browser and on a local server.

Was also told to checkout this fiddle to see shadow DOM in action: http://jsfiddle.net/wsCsp/14/ but that doesn't work for me either? There's nothing in about://flags that I see that would disable shadow DOM. caniuse says I can use it in Chrome 37.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createShadowRoot` is no longer vendor-prefixed in Chrome. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kxo9cqtt/)

In case you still want to support the vendor-prefixed variant (Android 4.x, old Chrome):

```
var root = (host.createShadowRoot || host.webkitCreateShadowRoot).call(host);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kxo9cqtt/1/)